# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchConfigurer'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I already went through the many link like : [Spring Batch with two different datasource issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537375/spring-batch-with-two-different-datasource-issue?rq=1), but I'm still getting the below error. I have configured the two datasource in the Spring Boot Batch application.

Below error -

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchConfigurer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to initialize Spring Batch
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:424) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1700) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.prateek.SpringBatchClassicDbApplication.main(SpringBatchClassicDbApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to initialize Spring Batch
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BasicBatchConfigurer.initialize(BasicBatchConfigurer.java:101) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:365) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:308) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikariConfig.java:1063) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:109) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:151) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:319) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:356) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType.fromMetaData(DatabaseType.java:100) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:183) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BasicBatchConfigurer.createJobRepository(BasicBatchConfigurer.java:131) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BasicBatchConfigurer.initialize(BasicBatchConfigurer.java:96) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

**CommonConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@PropertySource("classpath:scheduler.properties")
public class CommonConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.primary")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.secondary")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

**application.properites**

```
# DATA SOURCE
spring.primary.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/classicmodels
spring.primary.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.primary.datasource.username=root
spring.primary.datasource.password=root

spring.secondary.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/booking
spring.secondary.datasource.username=root
spring.secondary.datasource.password=root
spring.secondary.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

**EmployeesJob.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class EmployeesJob {
    public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd-MM-yyyy-hhmmssss";
    public static final DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("primaryDataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean 
    public EmployeesProcessor employeesProcessor() {
        return new EmployeesProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public EmployeesRunScheduler scheduler() {
        return new EmployeesRunScheduler();
    }

    // This file helps to create CSV column aliases
    @Bean
    public EmployeesFlatFileWriterCallback headerCallback() {
        return new EmployeesFlatFileWriterCallback();
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod="")
    @StepScope
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Employees> employeesReader(){
        JdbcCursorItemReader<Employees> itemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        itemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        itemReader.setSql("SELECT employeeNumber, lastName, firstName, extension, email, officeCode, reportsTo, jobTitle FROM employees ");
        itemReader.setRowMapper(new EmployeeRowMapper());
        // The fetch size can be controlled from the application.properties 
        //itemReader.setFetchSize(200);
        return itemReader;
    }


    @Bean(destroyMethod="")
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Employees> employeesWriter(){
        FlatFileItemWriter<Employees> fileItemWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        //fileItemWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource("csv/employees.csv"));
        fileItemWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource("csv/employees-{"+ formatter.format(new Date()) +"}.csv"));
        fileItemWriter.setHeaderCallback(headerCallback());

        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Employees> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
        fieldExtractor.setNames(new String[] {"employeeNumber", "lastName", "firstName", "extension", "email", "officeCode", "reportsTo", "jobTitle"});

        DelimitedLineAggregator<Employees> lineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
        lineAggregator.setDelimiter(",");
        lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);

        fileItemWriter.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator);

        return fileItemWriter;
    } 

    // Step Execution
    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Employees, Employees>chunk(10)
                .reader(employeesReader())
                .processor(employeesProcessor())
                .writer(employeesWriter())
                .build();
    }

    // Job Execution
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public Job exportEmployeesJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get("exportEmployeesJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(step1())
                .end()
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue like below :

```
@Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.dsmysql")
    public DataSourceProperties firstDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.dsmysql")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return firstDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.dspost")
    public DataSourceProperties secondDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.dspost")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return secondDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }
```

and add

```
spring.dsmysql.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required. Here is the issue in your code i.e prefix is not correct, update your code to following:

CommonConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@PropertySource("classpath:scheduler.properties")
public class CommonConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.primary.datasource")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.secondary.datasource")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

Please refer to this link https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7

Comment: Please see if you are missing any step https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7

Comment: Check if property file is in the classpath, the error is because it is unable to find properties

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174748/discussion-between-palsri-and-prateek).

Answer (score 0):

Check your application.properties file like below.

Note: springbatch is my DB name

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springbatch
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Vishal@123
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
```

---